# Converting astropy.table.columns to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I'd like to plot `points`:

```
points = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=(0,0), cov=[[0.4,9],[9,10]],size=int(1e4))

print(points)
  [[-2.50584156  2.77190372]
   [ 2.68192136 -3.83203819]
   ..., 
   [-1.10738221 -1.72058301]
   [ 3.75168017  5.6905342 ]]

print(type(points))
  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

data = ascii.read(datafile)  
type(data['ra'])
  astropy.table.column.Column
type(data['dec'])
 astropy.table.column.Column
```

and then I try:

```
points = np.array([data['ra']], [data['dec']])
```

and get a

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `numpy.array` is [`numpy.array(object, dtype=None,)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Hence, when calling `np.array([data['ra']], [data['dec']])`, `[data['ra']]` is the object to convert to a numpy array, and `[data['dec']]` is the data type, which is not understood (as the error says).

It's not actually clear from the question what you are trying to achieve instead - possibly something like

```
points = np.array([data['ra'], data['dec']])
```

Comment: I'm trying to put   data['ra']    and     data['dec'],    which are currently the astropy tables into a numpy array,   with the form:: [ [data['ra'][0], data['dec'][0] ...  [data['ra'][n], data['dec'][n]]

Comment: Since I don't have astropy installed, I cannot try anything out. Is the above working without error? What is its output?

Answer (score 5):

An astropy Table Column object can be converted to a numpy array using the `data` attribute:

```
In [7]: c = Column([1, 2, 3])

In [8]: c.data
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

You can also convert an entire table to a numpy structured array with the `as_array()` Table method (e.g. `data.as_array()` in your example).

BTW I think the actual problem is not about astropy `Column` but your numpy array creation statement.  It should probably be:

```
arr = np.array([data['ra'], data['dec']])
```

This works with `Column` objects.

Comment: While the accepted answer works, this is actually the more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, though, that if you actiually want is  to plot points you don't *need* to convert to arrays.  The following will work just fine:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(data['ra'], data['dec'])
```

With no need to do any conversion to arrays.