# How to convert a two column fits table into a 2D array in python

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I have a 2 column binary table held in a fits file and I'm reading it into my program using Table from astropy.table. I want to now store the values in a 2D array rather than a table but haven't found a way to do this. Any ideas on how to get started on this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the `.data` property of the table, should be an array. See also [Converting astropy.table.columns to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298554/converting-astropy-table-columns-to-a-numpy-array)